# Monitor certain part of memory for changes, such as data of record

Tags: delphi, debugging, memory, cpu, monitor

I am trying to read information which according to MSDN should be of type `VT_UI4`,
the equivalent of `Cardinal`.

The value in question is a WPD device `WPD_STORAGE_TYPE` which indicated what type of storage is present in the device.

The MSDN article suggest using the procedure `GetUnsignedInteger()`,
but in Delphi it keeps giving me an error.

However in Microsoft WPDInfo debug application, the value representing what I need to read is very well correctly presented.

However when populating a [`tag_inner_PROPVARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc235508.aspx) with the procedure `GetValue()` no error is returned, but I can't find the proper value to read from.

**I have done a test** using `CompareMem` by comparing two `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT` before calling `GetVaue()` to populate one of them and then comparing them again, and indeed the one passed to `GetValue()` gets populated.

**I have also** looked at the pointers in the populated `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT`
before it got populated, and after it got populated, and the pointers ranging from `pcVal` to `pdblVal` all get assigned after population.

So by using the CPU window or some kind of tool in Delphi should indicate which value is being changed. Right?

Basically, I'd like to monitor a chunk of memory, specific to a record or whatever defines the variable which points to `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this is what you're looking for because the text of your question is extremely unclear. However, this answer is based on the title of your question.

---

You can use a **data** [breakpoint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_and_Modifying_Breakpoints). Unlike a regular breakpoint which stops when a specific line of code is reached, a data breakpoint stops when a value in memory changes. You can then examine the call-stack to find out what lead to the change.

- Start your app through the debugger.
- In the breakpoint window: Click the down arrow next to "Add Breakpoint"

OR

- Select "Run > Add Breakpoint > Data Breakpoint" from the menu.

**TIP:** Although you're able to set the breakpoint using a variable/field, you may find it easier to figure out the specific address you want to watch and use that to set the breakpoint. This allows you to deal with the fact that a field of an object is duplicated for each instance of the the class.

Comment: @Aid You've provided basically zero useful information for anyone to help you with ***your*** problem. E.g. you say "Delphi keeps giving you an error" but can't be bothered to say what error. We don't even know whether it's a run-time or compile-time error. You're trying to read some information, but provide ***zero*** sample code. Suddenly half way through the question you talk about `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT`. Put yourself in our shoes, pretend you haven't seen you code at all. _How is `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT` even relevant?_ There is ***nothing*** clear in your question.

Comment: I understand. `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT` was referenced. I linked it to an MSDN article. How is it relevant? `GetValue()` needs it feeded in to its parameter list. I assumed I would get the point across as it isn't really about that specific record or variable, it is the memory data monitoring that the question is about, hence the title `Monitor certain part of memory for changes, such as data of record`. It might as well be a string type variable or a integer type variable.

Anyways I found a way to monitor the variable I was interested in.

Comment: When debugging, I added a breakpoint as you suggested (which I already knew, but good info nevetheless), and I put that breakpoint once BEFORE the `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT` was fed in to `GetValue()`, and then I added another breakpoint AFTER `GetValue()`, and then I ran with debugging. I noticed that theres a small window in the lower left corner which replaces the `Objecy Inspector`, it is called `Local Variables - Thread XXXXXX`, in there, I could monitor my `tag_inner_PROPVARIANT`and see changes at the two breakpoints.

Comment: @Aid No, you don't understand what Craig is telling you. Craig is telling you about a different kind of break point, the data break point. These can be used to make the debugger break whenever a range of memory addresses are modified. And in that way you don't need to identify all the possible places (some of which may be out of your control) that can modify a variable.

Comment: Oh, I'll look in to that.

Comment: @Aid, you said: "_I assumed I would get the point across as it isn't really about that specific record or variable, it is the memory data monitoring that the question is about_". I figured as much, which is why I focused on answering the title of your question. The point I was trying to make in my earlier comment is that the text of your question may seem clear to you, but that's only because you can see your code and the error messages you get. I must commend you for trying to provide context to your question, unfortunately to us it is disjointed.

Comment: @Aid By the way, I've edited my answer for clarity. You might want to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29202439/edit) your question as well. I suggest you re-read your question and pretend you have never seen the code you're asking about. This might help you to think about what information is missing. Knowing what information to put into a question is a tricky skill to master, but very worthwhile practising.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to monitor a variable, you could add one break point before the variable gets manipulated and one after it has been manipulated.

Then Run With Debugging and watch the variable in the `Local Variables - XXXXXX` window at the lower left corder. (Replaces the Object Inspector when running)

Comment: I don't see how this can be the answer to the question that the asker asked. I don't think we need to be told how to set break points and use the local variables window in the debugger. The documentation does that. If you want to ask very basic questions like, "how do I observe the value whilst debugging", then do so.

Comment: Well, you might not need to be told, but there are people out there that are new to programming that might find this info useful. Think about the unexperienced, David.

Comment: Indeed. But not in the answer to this particular question. Please do feel free to ask how "how do I observe a value whilst debugging".

Comment: I can't. It says that I've reached the amount of questions that can be asked by this account.